# jquery + css adding function call.

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I have a fixed div that is sliding in from the right when a imagebutton is clicked. The div then loads a separate html file. If I click the button again it toggles back in.

I would want to add a new "toggle"-button inside the sliding div that only slides the div back to hidden but when I try to add something inside the div it is not shown.

How can I accomplish this?

```
<Style>
#help_div
{
    position:fixed;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 500px;
    width:  500px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color:white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var inp;
    var posX;
    var posY;

        $(document).ready(function () {

        });

        //Helping DIV
        function DisplayHelp(input) {
            if ($("#input").attr("title") == input) { //|| $("div#help_div").css("display") == "none") {

            }

            if ($("div#help_div").css("display") == "none") {
                $("div#help_div").empty();
                $("div#help_div").animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 1000);
                $("div#help_div").load("helpfiles/" + input + ".html");
                inp = input;
            }
            else if(inp == input){
                $("div#help_div").animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 500);
                $("div#help_div").empty();
                inp = null;
            }
            else if (inp != input) {
                $("div#help_div").empty();
                $("div#help_div").load("helpfiles/" + input + ".html");
                inp = input;
            }
        }    
</script>


<div id="help_div" class="roundedCorners"></div>  
    <img src="/images/help_qa.png" onclick="DisplayHelp('help1')" alt="Helping text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code, to add new elements after loading your HTML page. :

```
$("div#help_div").append("<div> Hello </div>");
```

You said you tried adding new elements, where exactly did you try adding new elements to the div after loading ?